# Getting ORCIDs by DOI

Tags: doi, digital-researcher-id, cross-referencing

Is there a web service that retrieves all of the ORCIDs for the authors associated with a DOI?  I've looked at crossref.org, but I can't seem to find information on how to do this with their service.

I am currently using their HTTP-based API to query information about a publication given its DOI.  It returns the names of the authors, but not their ORCIDs.

(An ORCID (**O**pen **R**esearcher and **C**ontributor **ID**) is a unique identifier for an author of a publication.
A DOI (**D**igital **O**bject **I**dentifier) is the same thing, but for the publication itself)

Comment: Please consider editing your post to be more clear and helpful to those who, for example, might not know what ORCID and DOI stand for.  You'll probably get better responses that way too.

Comment: Did you try linking ORCID with SCOPUS Author ID?

Answer (score 2):

For biomedical publications it is possible to do using Europe PMC [API](https://europepmc.org/RestfulWebService) (I work for this database). You can query the database using the DOI like [this](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/europepmc/webservices/rest/search?resulttype=core&query=10.1038/s41598-018-21886-w) and extract (authorId type="ORCID") field. Here is the [same query using JSON](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/europepmc/webservices/rest/search?resulttype=core&format=json&query=10.1038/s41598-018-21886-w) is you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Well an ORCID is made for distinguish persons, and it really become useful precisely in case of homonyms. So with an ORCID you can get the matching author, but how could you get an ORCID from an author name, ie let's say, John Smith? The best you can get in a simple way would be a list of ORCIDs, with no mean to determine which one is correct. A more developed system could relate authors between them or use some other information (subject area, location, ...) to disambiguate and get back the correct ORCID. I don't know if such a system exists.

So the answer to your first question is "no". The simpliest way to get ORCID associated to an author would be if your "information about a publication given its DOI" would include ORCIDs itself.

Comment: "The best you can get in a simple way would be a list of ORCIDs, with no mean to determine which one is correct. ": well, I disagree, you can then list the publications of each of those ORCIDs, and see if one matches the DOI you provided. So, there is a way to do this (I don't know of any web service providing this service, but I don't think it is impossible either).

Comment: @Clément Yes this answer is maybe getting a bit outdated. But I still don't know a tool which automatizes a reverse-searching from article authors to their ORCID. Manually it's possible, as you said; you could also develop your own solution based on provided APIs.